# C# to SQL ExecuteReader() getting stuck

Tags: c#, sql

When running the below method in my application the app freezes and when I pause VS it seems to be stuck on the line that goes:

```
SqlDataReader reader = select.ExecuteReader();
```

I've got other SQL methods running fine so I know the connection string is correct, I've double checked the SQL and that's fine. Am I wrong in think the reader variable can not contain the returning value of the scalar function when the ExecuteReader() is called?

```
public static bool AccountValidation(string username, string password)
{
    string statement = "select dbo.AccountValidation('" + username + "','" + password + "')";
    SqlCommand select = new SqlCommand(statement, connect);
    connect.Open();
    SqlDataReader reader = select.ExecuteReader();
    string result = reader.ToString();
    connect.Close();

    if (result != "true")
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Slightly unrelated but you really should consider parameterizing your query as your current approach could potentially leave you vulnerable to nastiness like SQL Injection.

Comment: What do you expect reader.ToString() to do? Did you mean to do select.ExecuteScalar() instead?

Comment: Im not the first to say it but to reiterate, **Parameterize your queries**.  Your code is potentially vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.  You should also consider wrapping objects that implement `IDisposable` in `using` statements.

Comment: what is dbo.AccountValidation? a user-defined function, returning a scalar, or a table? you seem to expect it to return the string "true", in this case use it with the `ExecuteScalar` function. If you use a `DataReader`, you need to call its `Read()` method at least once to fetch.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main problem is that you are not actually reading anything back from the data reader, you have to iterate over the result set and then read based on ordinal/positional index.

There are also other big problems like

- Not using parameters which leaves the code vulnerable to sql injection attacks.
- Not wrapping your disposables in `using` blocks which could leave database connections open if there are exceptions
- sharing db connections in your types. Create connections on an as needed basis and then dispose them when you are done.

Here is your updated code with fixes. I guessed at the column types (varchar), fix that and the lengths as they are implemented in your schema.

```
public static bool AccountValidation(string username, string password)
{
    const string statement = "select dbo.AccountValidation(@username, @password)";
    string result = null;

    // reference assembly System.Configuration
    string connStr = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["YourDb"].ConnectionString;

    using(var connection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
    using(SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(statement, connect))
    {
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@username", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200){Value = username});
        cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@password", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200){Value = password});
        connect.Open();
        using(SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            if(reader.Read())
                result = reader.GetString(0); // read back the first column of the first row
        }
    }
    if (result != "true")
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

---

On a side note it would be cleaner to return a `bit` from your database function `AccountValidation` and then read that back with `reader.GetBoolean(0)` and assign that to the result and return that directly instead of doing string comparisons.

Also, as mentioned above in the comments, if you are only returning 1 value it is easier (and less code) to call `ExecuteScalar` instead of `ExecuteReader`.

Comment: Besides the redundant if statement at the bottom (thats on OP not you), this is the perfect answer.

Answer (score 1):

Add the line

```
reader.Read();
```

before the line

```
string result = reader.ToString();
```

Also, please parameterize your queries.

Comment: `reader.ToString()` will not return the first ordinal result. Most likely it will just return the default full type name. `reader.GetString(0)` will.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to leave a comment, but to answer part of your question, yes, you can use a SqlDataReader to read single scalar results with or without column aliases.